# Pearson Goodness-of-Fit Test

Tags: chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, count-data, negative-binomial-distribution

I am trying to compute the Pearson-Goodness-of-fit statistic for Count data to see if the mean and variance are correctly specified. I am using example data from Deb and Trivedi downloaded here: https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v027i08.

The Pearson statistic is calculated by: $P=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{(y_i-\mu_i)^2}{\mu_i+\sigma\mu_i^2}$ , where $\sigma$ is the dispersion parameter.
Since glm.nb presents $\theta$ because it uses the variance: $\mu+\mu^2/\theta$ i am transforming $\theta$ into $\sigma$.

Here is my code:

```
## data
load("DebTrivedi.rda")
View(DebTrivedi)
dt <- DebTrivedi[, c(1, 6:8, 13, 15, 18)]
View(dt)

### regression
fm_nbin <- glm.nb(ofp ~ ., data = dt)
summary(fm_nbin)
fitted<-fitted.values(fm_nbin)
nbsigma<-1/fm_nbin$theta
pearson<-sum(((dt$ofp-fitted)^2)/(fitted+nbsigma*(fitted^2)))
pearson
```

Cameron and Trivedi stated, that $E(P)=n$ if the mean and variance are correctly specified. In this case I've got $P=5549$ but I am not sure how to interpret this statistic. My question are:

-Was the transformation of nbsigma really necessary? Using $\theta$ I get $P=4073$ which looks better

-When is the Pearson statistics, considered as 'good'? Are there any criterias I can test for?

-If the mean and variance are not correctly specified, my estimations are biased. What should be the next step to achieve unbiased results?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: "*Cameron and Trivedi stated, that P=n if the mean and variance are correctly specified*" ... I'd find that somewhat surprising since Cameron & Trivedi surely know that a chi-squared statistic is a random variable and so will not be equal to a constant. Can you offer an exact quote (with a complete reference), please?

Comment: You are right. I've missunderstood something. 'If the mean and variance are correctly specified then $E[\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_i-\mu_i)^2\omega_i]=n$, because $E[(y_i-\mu_i)^2/\omega_i]=1$' (Cameron and Trivedi, 1998, p.151). I've corrected this in the question.

Comment: The expected value of the chi-squared statistic should be its degrees of freedom. I think there's a small error in one of the two equations you just gave there (note that only one of them has "/"), please double check.

Comment: `` where α is the dispersion parameter`` Cannot find $\alpha$.